# Unity Facebook SDK custom share

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to customize Unity's Facebook share dialog with title, description and picture?

I am working on a Unity game, targeting iOS and Android. I have installed the Facebook SDK 7.9.0. I am relatively new to Facebook development/implementation but I am quite familiar with the process.

I have search all over the internet for almost a week and I have not being able to find any example that works for me. I have tried everything from using the Unity Facebook SDK `FB.ShareLink` and `FB.FeedShare` methods to trying to open a web page with the open graph implementation of facebook share.

I read that these parameters (title, description and picture) where disables from April 2017 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/share-button) in the current and older versions of the Graph API, but there has to be a way because I still see some games and applications that have custom Facebook share dialog.

Unfortunately I am not allowed to post code, since I am working for a company.

P.S.: I know this is probably a topic, but most questions related to this topic where posted before the April 2017, so I am expecting more recent feedback.

Comment: You have to set og-tags on the URL you are sharing

Comment: Oh!!! The og-tags needs to be in the page that I am shearing? So then, for example, if I want to share when an achievement is unlocked, I can't just share a link to the game official website or to a generic achievements page, with custom title and image, I would have to create one page with custom og-tags (probably as part of the official website) for each achievement?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I see. That was helpulfull info thanks.